# Microsoft Graph Java client does not allow JVM to exit

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I an using Microsoft Graph Java client v 5.36.0 with azure-identity 1.60 with OKHttp azure-core-http-okhttp 1.11.2

Everything works fine except that the JVM does not exit after execution (I am using Eclipse to test).

The code is simple enough. After building the client if no requests are made the exits clean. However, if any request is made, the JVM does not exit.

Below are the line of code:

```
    final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId("--------------------------------------------")
            .clientSecret("----------------------------------------")
            .tenantId("--------------------------------------------")
            .build();

    List<String> scopes=new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

    final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = 
            new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);

    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                                        .builder()
                                        .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                                        .buildClient();

    MessageCollectionRequest req=graphClient
                                        .users("--").messages()
                                        .buildRequest(queryUnread,queryNoOfMails,queryExpandAttachment);
    MessageCollectionPage page=req.get();
    List<Message> messageList=page.getCurrentPage();
```

Rest of the processing comes here, nothing of any significance.

Now after the above call the main thread exits but the JVM is still active, as can be seen by the Eclipse red icon. Now my question is am I missing anything and therefore the JVM is not exiting or there is truly some issue with the library, which may be starting a thread and not exiting?

[image]

To experiment further, I created separate OKHttp client

```
    OkHttpClient httpClient=HttpClients.createDefault(tokenCredentialAuthProvider);
    
    GraphServiceClient graphClient=GraphServiceClient
                                    .builder()
                                    .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                                    .httpClient(httpClient)
                                    .buildClient();
```

And tried to close the client after execution

```
    System.out.println(httpClient.connectTimeoutMillis());//Prints 10000
    System.out.println(httpClient.connectionPool().connectionCount());//prints 1
    httpClient.connectionPool().evictAll();
    System.out.println(httpClient.connectionPool().connectionCount());//prints 0
    httpClient.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    System.out.println(httpClient.dispatcher().executorService().isShutdown());//prints true
```

The JVM still does not exit, therefore the issue is not will OKHttp pool ... where is the issue?

Comment: I have the same issue when I run it with `exec-maven-plugin` (`org.codehaus.mojo`). However everything works fine when compiled to a jar file.